# get TypeError when i import my own .py file

Tags: python, module

I am doing a sort program.i have two files called bubble(a bubble sort program) and cal_time(calculate the time),and they are in the same directory.

The problem is ,bubble work alone fluently.   however,when i import bubble to my cal_time file and callback bubble sort,the interpreter show me the error message,and obviously there is no built_in function or method in my code:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):    
>   File "F:/alogrithm/wzysort/cal_time.py", line 13, in <module>  
>       bubble.bubble_sort(generate_random_list())  
>   File "F:\alogrithm\wzysort\bubble.py", line 4, in bubble_sort  
>        if a[indx] > a[indx+1]:  
>     TypeError: unorderable types: builtin_function_or_method() > builtin_function_or_method()
> ```

cal_time.py:

```
import time
from wzysort import bubble
import random


def generate_random_list():
    result = []
    for i in range(10):
        result.append(random.random)
    return result

time_start = time.time()
bubble.bubble_sort(generate_random_list())
time_end = time.time()
print(time_end - time_start)
```

bubble.py:

```
def bubble_sort(a):
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    for indx in range(len(a[:-i-1])):
        if a[indx] > a[indx+1]:
            a[indx], a[indx + 1] = a[indx + 1], a[indx]
```

Comment: `random.random()` not `random.random` This has nothing to do with imports

Answer (score 2):

Your issue lies here:

```
result.append(random.random)
```

You are appending the method `random.random` onto the list – which has the type `builtin_function_or_method` (thus resulting in the error you are receiving – how would you compare functions?).

Instead, you want to call the method:

```
result.append(random.random())
```

Answer (score 0):

In `generate_random_list()` function, you are doing `random.random`. Since it is a function, you should write it as `random.random()`. Hence, the code of your `generate_random_list()` function should be:

```
def generate_random_list():
    result = []
    for i in range(10):
        result.append(random.random())
    return result
```